# Access elements in ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

I have developed an `ListView` into a dialog pop up, everything is working fine - listener for `Spinner` and `CheckBox`. I can access which element has changed value:

for spinner:

```
  @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
        Log.d("MyLog", "SPINNER at position: " + pos + " changed value to: " + parent.getItemAtPosition(pos));

    }
```

and for check box:

```
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            Log.d("MyLog", "changed value - is checked: " + isChecked);
        }
```

But **how** **can I accews title** - `TextView` of each `ListView` element, for example to set error if spinner changed element or checkBox changed state?

The view is look like:
[image]

**My whole code:**
xml base layout

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/dialog_base"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/title_dialog_zone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#30883D">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/dialog_imgView"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/material_margin_medium"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_alert" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/dialog_base_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/dialog_imgView"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/dialog_imgView"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/dialog_imgView"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/dialog_imgView"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="@string/txt_sys_dialog_caution"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/view_delimiter"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/material_margin_medium" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

custom element - can be TextView+TextView / TextView+CheckBox / TextView+Spinner:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_element_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/material_margin"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/material_margin"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:text="Ttitle Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/dialog_txtView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/dialog_element_title"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/material_margin_medium"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/material_margin"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/material_margin_large"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/material_margin"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/material_margin_large"
        android:hint="Here it is" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/dialog_checkBox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/dialog_element_title"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/material_margin_medium"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/material_margin_large"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/material_margin_large"
        android:checked="false"
        android:text="Do your choise" />

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/dialog_spinner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/dialog_element_title"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/material_margin_medium"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/material_margin"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/material_margin_large"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/material_margin"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/material_margin_large"
        android:background="#8E8276"
        android:popupBackground="#8E8276"
        android:spinnerMode="dropdown" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My dialog creation code is very long, but idea is to set up `BaseAdapter` using a JSON obj I choose what kind of view do I need to add in `ListView`. And I have adapters for `CheckBox` and `Spinner`.

Comment: Post the XML & the code showing how you set this up.

Comment: In your `onItemSelected()` method the `view` is the row. You should be able to call something like `view.findViewById(<id_of_the_TextView>));` to get your `TextView`.

Comment: Please post your activity and adapter codes..so we can understand where  you need help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something global to acces your child view, then you can handle that `ListView` row , but be carefully to not acces an invisible element - it will throw `NullPointerException`. One method can be to get your listView rows count after adapter is setted up:

```
                int cout = listView.getChildCount();
```

Then you can use a mthod like:

```
  public View getRowListViewByPosition(int itemPosition, ListView listView) {
    final int firstListItemPosition = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    final int lastListItemPosition = firstListItemPosition + listView.getChildCount() - 1;

    if (itemPosition < firstListItemPosition || itemPosition > lastListItemPosition ) {
        return listView.getAdapter().getView(itemPosition, null, listView);

    } else {
        final int childIndex = itemPosition - firstListItemPosition;
        return listView.getChildAt(childIndex);
    }
}
```

So, now you have the whole row, but you need only one element of your row, right? :)

```
View wantedViewRow = listView.getChildAt(1);
TextView txt = (TextView) wantedViewRow .findViewById(R.id.yourTitleTextView);
txt.setError("Sweet error!");
```

You're done! Tested solution...

Answer (score 0):

On checking of checkbox :

```
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            Log.d("MyLog", "changed value - is checked: " + isChecked);
if(isChecked)
titlecheck.setText("Checked");
else
titlecheck.setText("Unchecked");
        }
```

for Spinner do the same

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {



View parentRow = (View) view.getParent();

                    TextView title= (TextView) parentRow
                            .findViewById(R.id.title);
title.settext("android");


 }
```

try this..